# No Reverse Match in login view Django, html template parsing error

Tags: python, django, django-templates, html-templates

I have an issue with my django application.
My base.html template can be parsed in certain views but not in all of them and returns an error code

I do not have much experience with django but it seems to be that it can parse the template when the views aren't too far away from each other.

I also have a very bad structure, but I have no clue how to properly structure a django website.

login file (doesn't work):

```
<!--hovedside/templates/registration/login.html-->
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}
<h2>Login</h2>
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Login"></input>
</form>
<a href="{% url  dashboard %}">Back to dashboard</a>
{% endblock body %}
```

dashboard file (works):

```
<!--hovedside/templates/users/dashboard.html-->
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}
<div class="default-bodycontainer">
    <h1>Hello, {{ user.username|default:'Guest' }}!</h1>
</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

Filestructure for templates:
templates/base html
templates/registration/login html
templates/users/dashboard html

urls python file

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

app_name = "hovedside"
urlpatterns =[
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("dashboard/", views.dashboard, name="dashboard"),
    #path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
    url(r"^accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
]
```

problematic line from base.html:

```
<link rel="icon" href="{% static 'hovedside/img/favicon.ico' %}">
```

This is just the first line with static in the html template.
[Filestructure][1]

Full code here:
https://github.com/lolThinked/Stemdirekte

Errorcode below:
'''

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/stemdirekte/accounts/login/

Django Version: 3.1.4
Python Version: 3.6.6
Installed Applications:
['users',
 'hovedside.apps.HovedsideConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\Hopland Digital\Prosjekter\Stemdirekte\mysite\hovedside\templates\base.html, error at line 10
   Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
   1 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   2 : <html lang="en">
   3 : <head>
   4 :     <meta charset="UTF-8">
   5 :     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   6 :     <title>
   7 :         {{page_title}}
   8 :     </title>
   9 :     {% load static %}
   10 :     <link rel="icon" href=" {% static 'hovedside /img/favicon.ico' %}">
   11 :     <style>
   12 :         @font-face {
   13 :           font-family: 'BERNHC';
   14 :           src: local('BERNHC'),
   15 :                url('{% static "hovedside/fonts/BERNHC.ttf" %}'), format("truetype");
   16 :         }
   17 :         body{
   18 :             font-family: "BERNHC";
   19 :         }
   20 :     </style>


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\Files\Programmering\Stemdirekte\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\Files\Programmering\Stemdirekte\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 202, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\Files\Programmering\Stemdirekte\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\Files\Programmering\Stemdirekte\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\Files\Programmering\Stemdirekte\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\Files\Programmering\Stemdirekte\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\Files\Programmering\Stemdirekte\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\Files\Programmering\Stemdirekte\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\Files\Programmering\Stemdirekte\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\Files\Programmering\Stemdirekte\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\Files\Programmering\Stemdirekte\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\Files\Programmering\Stemdirekte\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\Files\Programmering\Stemdirekte\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\Files\Programmering\Stemdirekte\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\Files\Programmering\Stemdirekte\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\Files\Programmering\Stemdirekte\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\Files\Programmering\Stemdirekte\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\Files\Programmering\Stemdirekte\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\Files\Programmering\Stemdirekte\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /stemdirekte/accounts/login/
Exception Value: Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

'''
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9H0E.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your login template. It's trying to use the value of a variable named `dashboard` rather than the string `"dashboard"`.

```
<a href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">Back to dashboard</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Answer:***

```
<a href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">Back to dashboard</a>
```

as @schillingt pointed out I needed to point it to the string dashboard instead.

***Other issues:***

This also presented a later issue which I suppose is because of my structure, where I needed to link to

```
{% url 'hovedside:dashboard' %}
```

I then needed to add this not to the urls of the app hovedside but rather to the mysite application because the included links goes directly to:

> *accounts/login*

Instead of

> *stemdirekte/accounts/login*

So I needed to add those urls to the mysite urls insted like this.
*mysite/urls.py*:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("stemdirekte/", include("hovedside.urls")),
    path("hovedside/", include("hovedside.urls")),
    path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
]
```